# Passing arguments to SpeechRecognition Listener onResults

Tags: android, json, bluetooth, speech-to-text

Building an app that takes voice input and makes a JSON POST request to IFTTT via webhook.

When the user clicks a button on a bluetooth device, the app:

1. launches voice recognition
2. returns a string of transcribed speech
3. builds a custom url (from the event name saved in passed as an argument) based on what button was pressed
4. sends a JSON (which includes the voice string) POST request to the built url

In onResults of the SpeechRecognitionListener I call the function that builds the URL and makes the JSON POST request. However, I cannot pass the specific event name that is used to build the URL to onResults. The desired functionality is to have a method that takes eventName as a parameter and in onResults a webrequest is sent using this name. Therefore this method can be reused for multiple different events. E.g.:

```
SpeechIftttWebhook(event_name);
```

Trying to figure out the best practice for this problem. The code I use now, where the event name is hardcoded as a public variable:

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

     if (action.contains("trigger1")) {
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {

                mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                        PACKAGE_NAME);

                SpeechRecognitionListener listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener();
                mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
                mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
            }
        };
        mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
     }
}
```

Here is the SpeechRecognitionListener class:

```
class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {
    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech(){
        Log.i("SPEECH", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i("SPEECH", "onEndOfSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        Log.i("SPEECH", "onError: " + error);
        if (error == 7) {
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        } else {
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        Log.i("SPEECH_RESULT", String.valueOf(results));

        String note = matches.get(0);
        Log.i("SPEECH_RESULT_FIRST", speechText);

        //Get the event name and key from database
        String url = BuildIftttWebhookUrl(event_name, ifttt_key);
        Log.i("LINK", url);

        JSONObject json = buildIftttJson(note, null, null);

        makeJsonPostRequest(json, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    }
}
```

Here is the method that builds the IFTTT url:

```
public String BuildIftttWebhookUrl(String event, String key) {
    return ("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/" + event + "/with/key/" + key);
}
```

Here is the method that builds the JSON:

```
public JSONObject BuildIftttJson (String value1, String value2, String value3) {
    JSONObject iftttJson = new JSONObject();
    try {
        iftttJson.put("value1", value1);
        iftttJson.put("value2", value2);
        iftttJson.put("value3", value3);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return iftttJson;
}
```

Here is the JSON POST request method:

```
public String makeJsonPostRequest(JSONObject iftttJson, String url) {
    final HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    final String json = iftttJson.toString();
    Log.e("jsonn==> ", json);
    final String[] result = {null};
    try {
        //Connect
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        AsyncTask taskConnect = new AsyncTask() {...}
        AsyncTask taskWrite = new AsyncTask() {...}
        AsyncTask taskRead = new AsyncTask() {...}
```